# Adding row in a datagridview by pressing down key

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to add a row below by pressing down key when in the last row of a `DataGridView`.

But I can't capture key down or key pressed event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Down)
        {
            if (this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index == (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }

            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

}

I tried Your code Eplzong. But I can't use down key to transfer between rows Now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove * from last Row use DataGridView property `AllowUserToAddRows = False`.

And to add Row when in last row by pressing down key try this :

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {  
        if (keyData == Keys.Down)
        {
            if(this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index == (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }

            //selecting rows below current row
            if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1].Cells[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
            }
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code by when i press down key New Row is not appearing.

Comment: I updated my answer. I believe this is what you want.